# En Java, como puedo ejecutar un archivo de .exe especifico y que a la vez abra el archivo con ese mismo .exe?

Tags: java, archivo, cmd, exe

estoy en proceso de hacer un programa que pueda ejecutar un archivo .exe en especifico y que a la vez abra el archivo que quiero con ese mismo .exe. He intentado de muchas maneras pero no he podido hacerlo.
Este es el código que trate de utilizar pero no funciona, seguro lo uso mal. Espero que alguien me ayude.

```
//"ruta" es donde se encuentra el archivo .exe que deseo ejecutar.
//"Programa.68" es el archivo que quiero abrir con el mismo .exe que deseo ejecutar.

Runtime ob = Runtime.getRuntime();
    ob.exec(ruta + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" + "Programa.a68");
```

Comment: Debería ser algo como: `ob.exec("cmd "+ruta+" "+ System.getP`...

Comment: ya lo intenté de esa manera pero no me funcionó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con ayuda pude resolverlo, hice lo siguiente:

```
try{
    String[] comandoCMD= {"cmd.exe", "/c", "start", "cmd.exe","/k", rutaEXE + rutaArc};
                ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder(comandoCMD);
                Process proceso= pb.start();
}catch(Exception e){}

//rutaEXE = la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo .exe
//rutaArc= la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo que desea abrir con el .exe
```

Gracias a todos que me ayudaron.

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas prueba con lo siguiente:
exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)

Ejecuta el comando especificado en un proceso separado con el entorno(envp) y el directorio de trabajo especificados.

- comando es la ubicación del .exe
- envp puede ser nulo
- dir, es el directorio de su .exe

Con respecto a su código, debería ser :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\program files\\test\\test.exe", null, new File("c:\\program files\\test\\"));
```

Comment: lo probé,  pero sigo con el mismo problema, no me ejecuta el archivo. Así lo hice: exe.(escribí la ubicación del .exe , null, new File (la ubicación del archivo que deseo abrir con ese mismo .exe));